# Relay kit getSafeContract returns Error: Invalid SafeProxy contract address

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have been following the official docs(https://docs.safe.global/learn/safe-core/safe-core-account-abstraction-sdk/relay-kit) about relaying tx using gelato 1balance with the relay kit. However, I kept getting this error before getting the encoded safe tx.
[image]
I have logged the safeSDK.getContractVersion() part and it is the correct 1.3.0. The ethAdapter is also working fine - been using it for loading safe and swapping owner etc.

Can I get some help with why this error occured?

Thanks